# WP8 App misbehaving due to StreamWrite in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to save the results calculated on html page in a **textfile** using javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function () {
     var sw : StreamWriter = new StreamWriter("HTML_Results.txt");
     sr.Write('xyz");

     *** calculations ******
     sr.Write (result);
 }
</script>
```

by doing this, ***my WP8 App*** is misbehaving and not displaying images as usual. This app is an Image Fader (calculates FPS).

**Also tried:**

```
StreamWriter sr;
try {
    sr = new StreamWriter("\HTML5\HTMLResults.txt");
    sr.Write("xyz");
    File.SetAttributes("HTML5\HTMLResults.txt", FileAttributes.Hidden);
} catch(IOException ex) {
     console.write ("error writing"); //handling IO
}
```

**The aim is to:**

1. Extract calculated values of several html pages(after getting loaded
   one by one) in a single text file.
2. A Resultant HTML that reads this
   text file and displays results in a tabular format.

Is there a better way to this job or the above can be rectified and used? Appreciate help.

Comment: I've posted an answer below but I may well have misunderstood your question, which I think means it needs clarification. What is `StreamWriter`--is it a constructor object you have written yourself or one that you have pulled in from another library? There is no such native object in JavaScript.

Comment: I referred: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/c8e978f5-60a4-488b-b4a1-7a0e8d12338f

Comment: Okay, yes, as I say in my answer: that page is about Java code. But in this question you're trying to write in JavaScript, which is a completely different language. I upvoted your question though because you include the code and you are clear about what you are trying to do. It's just, as far as I know, what you're trying to do isn't possible in client-side JavaScript... unless you use an `<iframe>` perhaps... but I think you will need to familiarise yourself with some JavaScript first.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Do you suggest any other method for doing this job? Other than saving result in a file and then reading it later.

Comment: I assume you're trying to create a version of a phone app that works in a browser... is that right? What is the aim of the app? You mention it's an image fader but then why do you need to read and write files. I might be able to help but it all depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Exactly. This is a browser check app. The App fades the Image several times and calculates Frame rate (Frames/Sec). Another html page gets loaded that zooms in/out the text. This test will calculate Speed and other attributes. So a RESULTANT page (HTML) will have to extract calculated scores from both these tests and display in tabular format.

Comment: It's probably best to post this up as a different question so that it gets more attention from others. It would be good if you could link to an example of what you're trying to do too as it's hard to visualise. If you post it as another question, let me know and I'll take a look. (If you're feeling generous once you've done that, you could mark my answer below as correct to close this question off.)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've misunderstood your code but it looks like you're trying to write [Java within JavaScript scripting tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java). You cannot write Java in an HTML document. As far as I know, client-side JavaScript (which given your `<script>` tags is I guess what you're trying to write) can't perform the kind of file I/O operations you seem to want here.

You need to use [Node JS](http://nodejs.org/) to use JavaScript for something like that and then you're talking server-side. The closest you can get on client-side is using the new `localStorage` feature in HTML5 (not supported by all browsers).